# How to update computing nodes in a cluster?

Tags: linux, upgrade, nfs, cluster, file-server

I am in the process of small computing cluster assembly. It will run Ubuntu/Slurm for job scheduling. Only the head node will be connected to the Internet, all others will be accessible from the local network only. Each node will have a local HDD with OS and scratch space.

I am concerned about keeping OS up to date on each node in the simplest way possible.
**How would I go about updating the OS on each node?**
Should I share the network from the login node?
Or is there a way to download updates to the login node, put them on NFS storage and perform the cluster-wide updates?

Any ideas or suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: In addition to Slurm as the scheduler, you should have software such as Bright Cluster Manager to manage the cluster and the nodes contained therein themselves. Whoever the supports the software can give you more information on this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! Perhaps, I should have added that this is a low-budget initiative and we cannot afford comprehensive paid solutions right now.

Comment: Then what software are you using to manage the nodes in the cluster and have the compute and login nodes communicate with the head node?

Comment: I have not used any special software. Slurm was enough for all communications.

Comment: Then in that case, you're on your own. Slurm is just for managing the workloads. It doesn't do anything in terms of managing the nodes in the cluster. As you don't have anything to do that, then for updatubg the nodes, you're going to have to use trial and error to see what works and what doesn't work and you'll probably have things break. There's no way that anyone here can know exactly what you have or need even with details on the layout of your setup. You might want to consult with someone who can come onsite to see what you have.